# Show that there is precisely one cyclic code C of length 4 and dimension 2. Write down all the codewords in C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, cyclic-groups

I have shown there is one cyclic code, put not sure how to calculate the codewords in C.

I think that the generator matrix is \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

but am not sure, is that correct and if it is where do I go next?

Answer (score 3):

The rigorous way is to exploit the [algebraic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_code#Algebraic_structure) of cyclic codes: a cyclic code of size $(n=4,k=2)$ must have a generator poylnomial $g(x)$ of degree $n-k=2$, which must have a non null independent coefficient, and must be a factor of $1+x^{n}=1+x^4$

Now $1+x^{n}$ factors (remember we are in $GF(2)$) as  $$1+x^4=(1+x^2)^2=(1+x)^4$$

Hence there is a single possible generator polynomial $$g(x)=1+x^2$$

And the full code is

$$
\begin{array}{c c |c c}
      u  & u(x)  &     v(x)=u(x)g(x)     &   v\\
\hline
      00 &  0    &        0       &      0000\\
      10 &  1    &      1+x^2      &     1010\\
      01 &  x     &     x+x^3      &     0101\\
      11 &  1+x    &   1+x+x^2+x^3  &    1111\\
\end{array}
$$
Hence your matrix $G$ is right.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that, so is column V the 4 codewords?

Comment: Yes. They are the $2^k$ codewords

Answer (score 2):

Without using much algebra, note that the standard assumption that
a *cyclic* code is also a *linear* code ensures that one of the codewords must be $0000$. Cyclic shifts of this codeword are also in the code.
Now, only three remaining codewords need to be considered. Any length-$4$
vector such as $0001$ which has four distinct cyclic shifts 
$0001, 0010, 0100, 1000$ cannot be
a codeword in our cyclic code. A little thought (or just brute-force
writing out all $15$ possible codewords and discarding all that have
$4$ distinct cyclic shifts) then gets us to having $1111$ as another codeword, and $0101$ and $1010$ as the other two: they are the only
codewords with one distinct cyclic shift, and a cyclic shift of one
is the other (or itself).